# What does TVL-E13/2 mean?

Tags: phd, germany, salary

I know that the TVL system exists but I am not sure if TVL-E13/2 would mean it is 50% of TVL-E13 or what does the "/2" mean, could someone explain please? I've seen it in multiple PhD positions offers.

Comment: Yes, it means that you would be paid 50% of a salary of a full position. I will vote to close as off-topic.

Comment: @Snijderfrey Many other TVL questions have been deemed on topic.  Union contracts are an important part of academia, even if they apply to nonacademics too.

Comment: Which field is that? (Could matter as to whether this means 50% or level 2.)

Comment: Translational research / Biochemistry

Answer (score 2):

A good source of information regarding TV-L is the TV-L calculator at https://oeffentlicher-dienst.info/c/t/rechner/tv-l/west?id=tv-l-202, which is supported by current TV-L employees (but not actually official).
The calculator has the following main options (from top to bottom):

1. TV-L level, e.g. E13
2. TV-L stage (with increasing work experience, you get more money)
3. Percentage of a full position

The other options are useful to compute salary after taxes (taking pensions and healthcare costs into account), but are set to reasonable defaults.

After choosing options, click the gray "berechnen" button. The number marked in bold in the left column will be the exact salary before taxes, the bold number in the right row the salary estimation after taxes.

EDIT [Updated answer]: Regarding your specific question: /2 appears to most often refer to the percentage by which the position is funded, as you proposed. However there appears to be some ambiguity around this. Does the main body of these  adverts you're looking at contain more specific information?

Comment: In the given context, it is quite more likely that /2 refers to a fraction of 50% rather than level 2.

Comment: oeffentlicher-dienst.info is in no way "the official TV-L calculator". As their impressum states: "Öffentlicher-Dienst.info ist eine unabhängige Informations-Plattform für Mitarbeiter und Interessenten des öffentlichen Dienstes. Dieser Website ist weder 'amtlich' noch 'offiziell'!"

Comment: Thanks, I've removed the statement that this is an official source.

Comment: Regarding /2 as 50% - I have only ever seen the percentage written as a percentage, never as a fraction - so I would always assume /n refers to a pay grade stage [NRW]. Maybe this is state specific?

Comment: I haven't found any unambiguous information regarding the "/2" part of the question on the website you're referring to. But from googling some job ads that offer a "13/2 positon", it seems that the comments above are correct in that the "/2" denotes a fraction, i.e. this would be a part-time position. See e.g. https://www.uni-muenster.de/Rektorat/Stellen/ausschreibungen/st_20190410_sk12.html Moreover, it doesn't make much sense to include the Stufe in the job ad, since the *Stufeneinordnung* depends on the experience of the applicant and not on the job description.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I'll leave the answer up for now, but it is apparently more ambiguous than I thought. The /n notation is also used here https://oeffentlicher-dienst.info/tv-l/allg/hoehergruppierung.html to denote the stage. Regarding the purpose, maybe someone can confirm this, but from my understanding the university has some leeway whether to allow a higher Stufeneinordnung at all, so that is why I assumed they want to mention that they actually allow a higher stage.

Comment: @mirrormere I didn't catch that table. It seems this is hard to answer and the add is rather unclear.

Comment: I have never seen a TVL/TVÖD job offer that specifies an experience stage. I have seen many for part-time positions, particularly for phd positions. Some of them might even have specified as fraction but percentage or hours is the norm.

Comment: @mirrormere The stage *is* indeed denoted as "/n", just that job ads typically don't state the stage (since, as it is stated by others, it depends on experience, in either direction).